# Im trying to create a new array with with my fetched data and combine the incorrect_answers array with the correct answer inserted randomly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, backend

Heres my current code so far:

I am trying to pull random questions/ answers from this API. I am trying to now create a new array with all the answers together and the correct answer inserted randomly with the data saved in state and then be able to display it with data.question. (multiple choice quiz)

```js
export default function Quiz() {
  const [quizData, setQuizData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5&category=9&difficulty=easy&type=multiple"
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setQuizData(data.results));
  }, []);


  const quizQuestion = quizData.map((data) => {
    return (
      <div className="quiz-container">
        <h1>{data.question}</h1>
        <hr />
      </div>
    );
  });

  return <div className="">{quizQuestion}</div>;
}
```

I have tried to google various things the last few hours and am digging myself in a hole.

Comment: A help center link for markdown usage::  [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)